# How to use UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: swift

In C I would do something like this

```
int count = 10;
int *buffer;
num = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    buffer[i] = rand();
}
```

I have seen UnsafeMutablePointer used like this

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(count)
for i in 0..<count {
    buffer[i] = Int(arc4random())
}
```

How do I use UnsafeMutableBufferPointer for a C style buffer in Swift? Also, how would I realloc more space for the pointer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` doesn't own its memory, so you still have to use `UnsafeMutablePointer` to allocate the underlying memory. But then you can use the buffer pointer as a collection, and enumerate it using for-in loops.

```
let count = 50
let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(count)
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: count)
for (i, _) in buffer.enumerate() {
    buffer[i] = Int(arc4random())
}

// Do stuff...

ptr.dealloc(count)   // Don't forget to dealloc!
```

Swift pointers don't provide `realloc` functionality. You could use the C functions, or roll your own if you want do that.

Comment: Hi Khadpe, I have a relative question for several days,  please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662378/testcase-failed-after-converting-codes-from-objective-c-to-swift