# Testcase failed after converting codes from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unsafemutablepointer

I am doing some bitwise operations in Swift style, which these codes are originally written in Objective-C/C. I use `UnsafeMutablePointer` to state the beginning index of memory address and use `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` for accessing the element within the scope.

You can access the original Objective-C file [Here.](https://gist.github.com/wongzigii/e28257ae5b5c972bc6978001dc15db90)

```
public init(size: Int) {
    self.size = size
    self.bitsLength = (size + 31) / 32
    self.startIdx = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.alloc(bitsLength * sizeof(Int32))
    self.bits = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: startIdx, count: bitsLength)
}

/**
 * @param from first bit to check
 * @return index of first bit that is set, starting from the given index, or size if none are set
 *  at or beyond its given index
 */
public func nextSet(from: Int) -> Int {
    if from >= size { return size }
    var bitsOffset = from / 32
    var currentBits: Int32 = bits[bitsOffset]
    currentBits &= ~((1 << (from & 0x1F)) - 1).to32
    while currentBits == 0 {
        if ++bitsOffset == bitsLength {
            return size
        }
        currentBits = bits[bitsOffset]
    }
    let result: Int = bitsOffset * 32 + numberOfTrailingZeros(currentBits).toInt
    return result > size ? size : result
}

func numberOfTrailingZeros(i: Int32) -> Int {
    var i = i
    guard i != 0 else { return 32 }
    var n = 31
    var y: Int32
    y = i << 16
    if y != 0 { n = n - 16; i = y }
    y = i << 8
    if y != 0 { n = n - 8; i = y }
    y = i << 4
    if y != 0 { n = n - 4; i = y }
    y = i << 2
    if y != 0 { n = n - 2; i = y }
    return n - Int((UInt((i << 1)) >> 31))
}
```

Testcase:

```
func testGetNextSet1() {
    // Passed
    var bits = BitArray(size: 32)
    for i in 0..<bits.size {
        XCTAssertEqual(32, bits.nextSet(i), "\(i)")
    }
    // Failed
    bits = BitArray(size: 34)
    for i in 0..<bits.size {
        XCTAssertEqual(34, bits.nextSet(i), "\(i)")
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me why the second testcase fail but the objective-c version pass ?

**Edit:** As @vacawama mentioned: If you break testGetNextSet into 2 tests, both pass.

**Edit2:** When I run tests with `xctool`, and tests which calling `BitArray`'s `nextSet()` will crash while running.

Comment: How are `.toInt` and `.to32` implemented?

Comment: @vacawama It's an extension of Int `public var to32：Int32｛return Int32(truncatingBitPattern：self)｝`

Comment: This statement is troublesome: `return n - Int((UInt((i << 1)) >> 31))`.  If `i` is negative, this will crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C version of `numberOfTrailingZeros`:

```
// Ported from OpenJDK Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros implementation
- (int32_t)numberOfTrailingZeros:(int32_t)i {
    int32_t y;
    if (i == 0) return 32;
    int32_t n = 31;
    y = i <<16; if (y != 0) { n = n -16; i = y; }
    y = i << 8; if (y != 0) { n = n - 8; i = y; }
    y = i << 4; if (y != 0) { n = n - 4; i = y; }
    y = i << 2; if (y != 0) { n = n - 2; i = y; }
    return n - (int32_t)((uint32_t)(i << 1) >> 31);
}
```

When translating `numberOfTrailingZeros`, you changed the return value from `Int32` to `Int`.  That is fine, but the last line of the function is not operating properly as you translated it.

In `numberOfTrailingZeros`, replace this:

```
return n - Int((UInt((i << 1)) >> 31))
```

With this:

```
return n - Int(UInt32(bitPattern: i << 1) >> 31)
```

The cast to `UInt32` removes all but the lower 32 bits.  Since you were casting to `UInt`, you weren't removing those bits.  It is necessary to use `bitPattern` to make this happen.

Comment: It looks like that `XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(34)") is not equal to ("Optional(32)") ` which shows 34 times.

Comment: It's working for me if I test on a 64-bit device (iPhone 5S and later).  Can you update your question to show all of your code (including implementations of `.toInt`, `.to32`, and the rest of the `BitArray` implementation.  Perhaps I did it differently.

Comment: I just uploaded an example repo [here](https://github.com/wongzigii/SwiftBit), please checkout for more info.

Comment: First, shouldn't the second assert in `testGetNextSet` be             `XCTAssertEqual(34, array.nextSet(i), "\(i)")` ?  Why is it referencing `bitArray`.  The same goes for the loop. But even with that change `testGetNextSet` fails.  Weird.  If you break `testGetNextSet` into 2 tests, both pass.

Comment: Exactly, I just made a typo, sorry for that stupid mistake.

Comment: I've posted a new answer about how I finally figured out this issue. Anyway, thanks for your points.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that `startIdx` just need to be initialized after allocation.

```
self.startIdx = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.alloc(bitsLength * sizeof(Int32))
self.startIdx.initializeFrom(Array(count: bitsLength, repeatedValue: 0))
```

Or use `calloc` with just one line code:

```
self.startIdx = unsafeBitCast(calloc(bitsLength, sizeof(Int32)), UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.self)
```

Furthermore, I use `lazy var` to defer the Initialization of `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` until the property is first used.

```
lazy var bits: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int32> = {
   return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int32>(start: self.startIdx, count: self.bitsLength)
}()
```

On the other hand, don't forget to `deinit`:

```
deinit {
    startIdx.destroy()
    startIdx.dealloc(bitsLength * sizeof(Int32))
}
```